# Ansible: Accessing standard user home path while being logged in as root

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy a file using ansible as sudo from remote user home directory `~/bin` to `usr/local`.

This works:

```
- name: Copy Folder Working
  become_user: "{{ ansible_facts.env.SUDO_USER }}"
  become: yes
  command: sudo mv ~/bin /usr/local/bin
```

But this doesn't:

```
- name: Copy Folder Permission Error
  become_user: "{{ ansible_facts.env.SUDO_USER }}"
  become: yes
  copy:
    remote_src: yes
    src: ~/bin
    dest: /usr/share
```

So even though I use `become: yes` ansible apparently doesn't copy using sudo. I do get the same permission error as if I would try to copy the file manually without using sudo. The paths seem to be correct. How can I avoid that or is sticking to the first self implemented solution the way to go?

**Additional Info**

This is part of a playbook that is executed on a server. That server can have `ubuntu` as its default user, but also any other default user of a Linux distribution is possible. Therefore the default user needs to be read from `ansible_facts` as I try to do by using `"{{ ansible_facts.env.SUDO_USER }}"`. While `SUDO_USER` sounds odd this seems to work as I get the expected permission error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_original_basename": null,
            "attributes": null,
            "backup": false,
            "checksum": null,
            "content": null,
            "dest": "/usr/share",
            "directory_mode": null,
            "follow": false,
            "force": true,
            "group": null,
            "local_follow": null,
            "mode": null,
            "owner": null,
            "remote_src": true,
            "selevel": null,
            "serole": null,
            "setype": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "src": "/home/ubuntu/bin",
            "unsafe_writes": false,
            "validate": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Destination /usr/share not writable"
}
```

There's also the issue I need to fix that it merges instead of copying, but there are multiple possible solutions for that which I feel are unrelated (for example copying the files from `~/bin/*` instead and deleting the folder.

Comment: Your first command uses sudo twice i.e. remote_user -> ansible_facts.env.SUDO_USER -> root. Your second command copies the file as ansible_facts.env.SUDO_USER. Without further information it's hard to give you an hint on how to resolve your problem.

Comment: Connect directly as that user and drop become_user from your copy task so it uses root by default.

Comment: You are not using root by default as `become_user` in the above example. You're not setting explicitely `default-usr` anywhere either. So I don't understand your problem in the question which is not aligned to your latest info in comment (which should be an [edit] to your question anyway).

Comment: If I would use `become_user: root` `~/bin` would be evaluated to `/root/bin`. Therefore I am becoming `ubuntu` to get the right home path evaluation. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Become `root`, and copy to `~{{ ansible_facts.env.SUDO_USER }}/bin`.

Comment: This works and looks like to be the natural solution to me. If you care to make this an answer and explain why this works, I will accept it as an answer.